# Vue 3: wrap all items within a slot with a custom component by using a render function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-render-function

I am trying to build my own **sortable** component. I want to pass a list of items to it's default slot. The sortable component should then wrap all passed items with a custom `v-draggable` component.

```
<v-sortable handle=".handle">
    <template :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <some-complex-component :item="item"></some-complex-component>
    </template>
</v-sortable>
```

Now withn my `v-sortable` component I am trying to wrap all given nodes within default slot with a custom `v-draggable` component.
My `v-sortable` component looks like this:

```
import { h } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'v-sortable',
    props: {
        handle: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: () => {
                return null;
            }
        },
    },
    render () {
        const draggableItems = this.$slots.default().map(slotItem =>
            h('v-draggable', { handle: this.handle }, [slotItem])
        )
        return draggableItems;
    }
}
```

This works as expected, except that my custom component `v-draggable` will not be rendered as a vue component. All items will be wrapped in html tags called `<v-draggable>`.
How would I have to proceed to actually parse the `v-draggable` component as Vue component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to import it and register and use it directly :

```js
import { h } from 'vue';
import VDraggable from 'path/to/v-draggable'
export default {
    name: 'v-sortable',
    props: {
        handle: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: () => {
                return null;
            }
        },
    },
    render () {
        const draggableItems = this.$slots.default().map(slotItem =>
            h(VDraggable, { handle: this.handle }, [slotItem])
        )
        return draggableItems;
    }
}
```

It's recommended to pass items as prop and use them directly inside the render function :

```html
<v-sortable handle=".handle" :items="items">
</v-sortable>
```

child component :

```js
import { h } from 'vue';
import VDraggable from 'path/to/v-draggable'
export default {
    name: 'v-sortable',
    props: {
        items:{
         type:Array,
         default: () =>[]
        },
        handle: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: () => {
                return null;
            }
        },
    },
    render () {
        const draggableItems = this.items.map(slotItem =>
            h(VDraggable, { handle: this.handle }, [item])
        )
        return draggableItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure 'v-draggable' won't work without resolveComponent, render function is low-level and works similarly to React in this regard, where string types are for HTML elements

Comment: Great, it works. Only problem I still have is that the component is wrapped around the whole slot and not around each item. Maybe something wrong with the way I use the map() function.

Comment: Btw: register with `components: { VDraggable }` seems not to be neccessary in this case.

Comment: @EricXyz please check my edited answer

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Actually in my scenario the items are not just an array of strings but a complex template with  other components. I just simplyfied it for this question. 
So as I do not know which structure the items array has, I can not pass it as a prop. This way sortable component does not have to know anything about the slots inner content structure.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in codesandbox?

Answer (score 3):

The component can to be explicitly specified in render function:

```
h(VDraggable, ...)
```

Globally registered component that isn't available for import (e.g. from third-party libs) can be resolved from a name with [`resolveComponent`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#resolvecomponent).

Comment: Great, thanks for the hint with "resolveComponent"!